# How to find closest date time from list of date time?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this list of time taken from mysql database:

2011-07-22 10:12:53
**2011-07-22 10:17:53**
2011-07-22 10:19:42
2011-07-22 10:29:31

Right now i want to get the closest date time from the bold date time. Only the date time after the bold one will be valid, and it must be the closest. So the desired result is **2011-07-22 10:19:42**

How to solve this using php or mysql?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm sure this has been asked a many times..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SELECT ABS(time_to_sec(timediff(col_with_date,'$date'))) AS time_distance
FROM table_with_date
ORDER BY time_distance
LIMIT 1;

Answer (score 1):

```
   WHERE datefield < '2011-07-22 10:19:42'
ORDER BY datefield DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

?

Comment: thanks, you give me some idea to work on. and btw i have a duplicate date time in the question and already edited it.

Comment: So i think order by datefield desc is not needed here.